# Can I convert a string into a Variable in UiPath?

Tags: .net, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I have a couple argument variables like this:

```
in_Topic = "New Topic"
in_Meeting = "Demo Meeting"
```

Also I have a dictionary

```
myDict = {"Topic": "in_Topic", "Meeting":"Demo Meeting"}
```

How can I link the Value in the dictionary to be the variable?

For example:
myDict("Topic") = "New Topic"

This is in UiPath by the way.

There are different ways but I could not figure this part out. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just add it with the `Assign` activity:

[image]

[image]